# Make image of slider fit 100% parent container

Tags: html, css

I have an `slider` with Bootstrap. In the `XL` version shows good, but when you resize the Window and the right `container` of text grow his `height`, the image didn't fit the `parent container` to adapt his `height` to make the same height that the `container` text. You can see an live example [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/), in the middle section of the page.

So, in the XL version:

[image]

But if you resize the `width` of the Window, the container text's `height` grow, not happens the same `with` the image of the slider, happening that:

[image]

Now the code:

```
  <div class="container-fluid mejores-instalaciones">
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 no-padding">
<div id="carouselExampleControls2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/mejores-instalaciones/slider/slider-mejores-instalaciones-1.jpg" alt="Niñas haciendo yoga" title="Niñas haciendo yoga">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/mejores-instalaciones/slider/slider-mejores-instalaciones-2.jpg" alt="Jugando al tenis" title="Jugando al tenis"> 
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/mejores-instalaciones/slider/slider-mejores-instalaciones-3.jpg" alt="El comedor" title="El comedor">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/mejores-instalaciones/slider/slider-mejores-instalaciones-4.jpg" alt="La entrada" title="La entrada">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/mejores-instalaciones/slider/slider-mejores-instalaciones-5.jpg" alt="La biblioteca" title="La biblioteca">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <h1 class="desc text-right">LAS MEJORES INSTALACIONES DE EXTREMADURA</h1>
      <p class="home-text-p text-right">La RUCAB es un referente en Extremadura desde hace 32 años, cuanta con el mayor numero de plazas, un total de 205, repartidas en 36 habitaciones dobles, 132 habitaciones individuales y una habitación adaptada. La construcción se extiende por una amplia zona ajardinada, con seis edificios o núcleos residenciales, además de los edificios de las zonas comunes. El total de superficie construida es de 8.492 m².</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried `height:100%` or `background-size:cover` for carousel class in css

Comment: yes but didn't worked

Comment: maybe try `object-fit: fill` on the image?

Comment: Instead displaying the `<img>` tag, can you display a `div` that has the img as the background, and then add `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: @Code_Ninja But it's a bit strange because the Bootstrap slider normally don't make with background images, right?

Comment: only the basic structure needs to followed to implement the slider, if that structure needs `img` tags, then my approach wont work, otherwise, you can use that approach and the slides can be customized better.

Comment: you can still try by putting `div` instead of the `img` tag.